# VBA: Range Syntax Confusion

Tags: vba, excel, named-ranges

What is the difference between

```
Range("A1","A40").Select 
Range("A1:A40").Select
```

Though both of them produce the same result. I would like to know the difference between them

Comment: I guess there's no difference it's just two different ways of doing the same thing. Syntax is `Range(Cell1.Address,Cell2.Address)` where `Cell2.Address` is optional. The correct question would be "what's the difference between Cell and Range ?".

Comment: Eg. You can also do `Range("A1:A40","A80").Select` which will select A1 to A80 Cells.

Comment: AFAIK a cell is a range,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference. It is only a form of easiness in vBA language that let you assign or call the same objects' properties or methods in many different ways.

You can also select the same range with the following syntax

```
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 40))
```

While I might understand your confusion if you have practiced other "strict" programming languages, this should not disturb you. Just view this as more flexibility provided by vba language and syntax